# अग्निः सजीवः अस्ति अथवा निर्जीवः (Is Agni alive or dead entity)?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, agni

According to Hinduism, things like stone etc are called निर्जीव or अचेतन (dead) because stone has no consciousness and it doesn't feel pain.

The same goes for Agni, it looks like निर्जीव, but Veda tell us that Agni created this universe, so does that mean Agni is alive, but it doesn't seem alive when we look at it. So, is Agni dead or alive?

If you say Agni is alive because ब्रह्मन् is everywhere then why the special status for Agni, we should treat Agni and stone alike. Isn't it?

Comment: @YDS I asked that question 2 years ago. Back then that answer was acceptable to me. The answer is basically saying that Agni is different from Agni deva but when studying the Veda over these years I've came to know that there's no such distinction made between Agni and Agni deva. So, that answer is no more acceptable to me.

Comment: I am just analyzing the question, not answering. First of all Addressing the exact definition of Aliveness is important. In the first para: Nirjiv does not mean dead, they never lived- they are non-living, only a living has the ability to die. 2nd para: It has views from both pure science and scripture. Also not everything that can creat is alive? 3rd para: Agni and stone are already diffrent, a stone cannot burn anything, fire does it. Why the special status? That's the question that can be answered.

Comment: We mark Q as duplicate to another question and not answer..this is still a duplicate even if answer is not there or wrong or invalid..people should answer that Q and not this..

Comment: That was asked with respect to events from Puranas but this asks in the context of Vedas. That's how it's not a duplicate.